# Excel VBA - Update cell with existing value + user form input

Tags: vba, excel

Background: My team would like to use a shared Excel workbook to track time spent on TFS work items.  We figure this can be done easily using VBA, but we're new to VBA and can't quite find the combination of what works.

After linking to TFS, we have a table which may look something like this:

```
ID |Title | Description | Category | State             | Completed Work
===========================================================================
140 Test 1  VBA is fun    Testing    Programming         0
141 Test 2  VBA is great  Testing    Programming         0
142 Test 3  Testing VBA   Testing    Programming         0
143 Test 4  Need help     Testing    Programming         0
144 Test 5  Questions     Testing    Programming         0
```

We want to update the Completed Work field based on entries from a pop-up form.  (Or, better yet, have the form directly on the worksheet.)

The form part is easy.  It will have only two text boxes: Ticket ID and Time Spent.  As well as an Update control button.  When both text boxes are entered and Update is clicked, it should add Time Spent to Completed Work field for the Ticket ID supplied.  What we can't get right is the code to make that happen.  I expect it will be some combination of If / Then / Else and loops.

Specifically we need help with the following...

1) Once Ticket ID and Time Spent are entered, and "Update" button is clicked, this is the desired behavior:

- Search worksheet to find the ID column (location of ID column may change)
- Search this column for Ticket ID supplied by user
- If a match is found, search adjacent cells to find the Completed Work column (location of Completed Work column may also change). Else trigger error message and close
- Get existing value in Completed Work column, and add value from Time Spent text box
- Update value in Completed Work column with the new total

The following is very much simplified and doesn't work anyway.  But to give an idea:

```
Private Sub UpdateCompletedWork_Click()

   Dim ExistingCompletedWork AS Integer

   If Sheet1.Range("A1:G100").Value = IDTextBox.Value
   Then ExistingCompletedWork.Value = Sheet1.Range([Completed Work field in same row])

   [Completed Work field] = ExistingCompletedWork.Value + TimeSpentTextBox.Value 

   Else MsgBox("ID Not Found")

End Sub
```

How do we find a location of a cell based off the column name AND value of a text box on a user form?

Once that's found, how can we look through cells on the same row to get the value of another cell, based on its column name?

2) If a user has an ID highlighted (active cell), we want to automatically populate the Ticket ID text box in the form.  How can we accomplish this?  I figured it would be as easy as setting it to active cell value on initialization:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    IDTextBox.Value = ActiveCell.Value

End Sub
```

But that fails with Run-time Error 424: Object Required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few questions on how you have the workbook set up. Is the table actually set up as a table? As that would make it easier to find the "Completed work" column. If not, there are multiple ways of finding the column number. Will the ID column ever change? Is the completed work column always going to be the last column?

What if the activecell isn't an ID? You should have a check built in for that.

Edit:

```
Private Sub UpdateCompletedWork_Click()
Dim IDrow as Range
idColumn = Range("TFS[ID]").Column
workColumn = Range("TFS[Completed Work]").Column
If Len(IDTextBox.Value) > 0 And Len(TimeSpentTextBox.Value) > 0 Then
ID = IDTextBox.Value
timeSpent = TimeSpentTextBox.Value
set IDrow = Columns(idColumn).Find(ID)
If Not IDrow is Nothing then
Cells(IDrow.row, workColumn).Value = Cells(IDrow.row, workColumn).Value + timeSpent
Else
MsgBox "Not a valid ID."
End If
End If
End Sub
```

And also

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
idColumn = Range("TFS[ID]").Column
If idColumn = ActiveCell.Column Then
IDTextBox.Value = ActiveCell.Value
End If
End Sub
```

You will just need to update the variables that you want. Also TFS is just the name of the table I used. It will need to match the table in the workbook.

Comment: It is indeed a table, as when you link to TFS to pull work item info, it automatically creates the resulting data as a table.  The locations of both the ID and Completed Work columns might change (it's possible to rearrange or add columns from TFS), but the names will never change.

Great idea checking that ID is an integer.  I think we can use IsNumeric to do that?

Comment: Well you might also want to search for the ID column and see if the activecell.column is that same column, then populate the textbox.

Comment: I updated my initial answer with both subs that would solve the issue you are working on. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks so much, works great!  Just one follow up question...how might I check if the ID entered doesn't exist on the worksheet?  I thought maybe something like IsNull(Cells(IDrow, idColumn).Value), presuming that if IDRow is not found it would be null, but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: In the process of testing I also noticed that the ID doesn't have to be exact.  It will take a partial match.  Meaning, using the example I posted, if I put in 2 for the ID, it will find and update 142.  How can we make it an exact match?

Comment: I found the answer to my last comment (need to add lookat:=xlWhole to the Find method) but then it just causes an error.  Time to look into error handling!

Comment: Ok, I see what you are looking for, sorry I should have included that part. I have updated my code above to account for the ID not existing. I changed the code to make IDrow a range and using set will cause it to set it to nothing if it can't be found. You will also need to update the IDrow.row part of the cells() line.

Comment: Your code below works as well. Glad you were able to find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final result we came up with (though histerical's looks like a simpler way).  We may add more for error handling later on, but this works for now.  Thanks again to histerical!

One quick note for those who may be hoping to do the same thing with TFS: The name of the table is randomly generated and cannot be updated.  The name "TFS" wouldn't actually work.  That means that you'll need separate code for each TFS query you want to apply this to.  Thus, not a good solution for larger groups.  Maybe someone could recommend a way around this?

`Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    IDColumn = Range("TFS").Column
    If IDColumn = ActiveCell.Column Then
       IDTextBox.Value = ActiveCell.Value
    End If
End Sub`

```
Private Sub EnterTime_Click()
    'Find columns
    IDColumn = Range("TFS"[ID]").Column
    WorkColumn = Range("TFS"[Completed Work]").Column
    'Error if ID or Time not entered
    If Len(IDTextBox.Value) > 0 And Len(TimeSpentTextBox.Value) < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Enter Hours"
    End If
    IF Len(TimeSpentTextBox.Value) > 0 And Len(IDTextBox.Value) < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Enter ID"
    End If

FieldChecks:
    If Len(IDTextBox.Value) > 0 And Len(TimeSpentTextBox.Value) > 0 Then
        ID = IDTextBox.Value
        TimeSpent = TimeSpentTextBox.Value
        On Error GoTo IDError
        IDRow = Columns(IDColumn).Find(ID, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        If IsNumeric(IDTextBox) = False Then
            MsgBox ("Invalid ID")
        End If
        Cells(IDRow, WorkColumn).Value = Cells(IDRow, WorkColumn).Value + TimeSpent
    End If

IDError:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "ID Not Found. Enter Valid ID."
        IDTextBox.Value = ""
        Resume FieldChecks
    End If

End Sub
```